# MSVC natstepfilter - how to exclude "operator new"?

Tags: visual-c++, new-operator, operator-keyword

I have custom global new operator (without any namespace):

```
void* operator new(size_t nSize)
{ ... }
```

I am trying to exclude it from debugging by using .natstepfilter file:

```
<StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">
  <Function><Name>operator new</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
  <Function><Name>.*operator new.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
  <Function><Name>.*operator\snew.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
  <Function><Name>.*::operator new.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
  ...
</StepFilter>
```

But all of these tries didn't work. The other functions in the filtering are excluded normally, so the file itself is working.

How to exclude global custom operator new?